# Docbook, Images, ANT

Tags: xml, ant, xerces, docbook

I'm trying to convert a DocBook XML - File via XSLT to HTML. The XML - File contains an image, which is why I get the following error:

```
build-html:
     [xslt] Transforming into C:\dev\DocBook\DocBookmitXML\output
     [xslt] Processing C:\dev\DocBook\DocBookmitXML\src\BurndownChart.jpg to C:\dev\DocBook\DocBookmitXML\output\BurndownChart.html
     [xslt] Loading stylesheet C:\dev\DocBook\DocBookmitXML\docbook-xsl-1.75.1\xhtml\docbook.xsl
     [xslt] : Fatal Error! org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence. Cause: org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
     [xslt] Failed to process null
```

---

**The DocBook-File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE article SYSTEM "../docbook-xml-4/docbookx.dtd" >
<article>
    <articleinfo>
        <title>Freitags um 11.30 Uhr</title>
        <author>
            <firstname>me, myself </firstname>
            <surname>and I</surname>
        </author>
    </articleinfo>
    <sect1 label="1.0"> 
        <title>An introduction to DocBook</title>
        <para>this is text</para>
    </sect1>
    <sect1 label="2.0">
        <title>Core Docbook</title>
        <para>
            <table frame='all'>
                <title>Testtabelle</title>
                <tgroup cols="3">
                    <thead>
                        <row>
                            <entry>Monat</entry>
                            <entry>Woche</entry>
                            <entry>Besucher</entry>
                        </row>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <row>
                            <entry>Mai</entry>
                            <entry>1</entry>
                            <entry>4711</entry>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <entry>Mai</entry>
                            <entry>2</entry>
                            <entry>4712</entry>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <entry>Mai</entry>
                            <entry>3</entry>
                            <entry>4713</entry>
                        </row>
                        <row>
                            <entry>Gesamt</entry>
                            <entry></entry>
                            <entry>47110</entry>
                        </row>
                    </tbody>
                </tgroup>
            </table>
        now to the difficult stuff... 
        </para>
    </sect1>
    <sect1 label="2.0">
        <title>A Picture</title> 

            <mediaobject>
                <imageobject>
                    <imagedata format="JPEG" fileref="BurndownChart.jpeg" />
                </imageobject>
            </mediaobject>

    </sect1>
</article>
```

---

**The Build-File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project name="docbook-src" default="build-html">
    <property name="docbook.xsl.dir" value="./docbook-xsl-1.75.1/xhtml" />
    <property name="doc.dir" value="output" />
    <property name="src" value="src" />
    <property name="html.stylesheet" value="${docbook.xsl.dir}/docbook.xsl" />
    <property name="xalan.lib.dir" value="./xalan-j_2_7_1"/>

    <path id="xalan.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${xalan.lib.dir}" id="xalan.fileset">
            <include name="xalan.jar" />
            <include name="xercesImpl.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleans up the generated files">
        <delete dir="${doc.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="depends">
        <mkdir dir="${doc.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="build-html" depends="clean,depends" description="Generates HTML files from DocBook">
    <xslt basedir="src" destdir="${doc.dir}" style="${html.stylesheet}" extension=".html">
            <classpath refid="xalan.classpath" />
        </xslt>
    </target>
</project>
```

---

Where should I look for the error?

Comment: hmmm... half of the DocBookfile was not recognized

Comment: hmmm....have you validated that DocBook XML file? Maybe there is a error in it? Second Thought: How is encoding involved in processing a simple file? Just some thoughts...

Comment: The XML File validates without complaints. Everything is fine... until i add the mediaObjekt

Answer (score 2):

If you take a careful look at the error message, you'll notice that it's actually trying to process the JPEG file, which will of course fail. By default when invoked this way, the [`xslt`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) task will try to transform all files it finds in the specified directory. You can add add an attribute like `includes="*.xml"` to tell it to process *.xml files only.